# Why do results differ from the Java version of this loop?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to write a piece of code in which should return the number of trailing zeroes in n!

The following is the code that I've written:

```
def countzeroes(n):
    count = 0
    i = 5
    while n/i >= 1:
        count += n/i
        i *=5
    return count

print(countzeroes(100))
```

Now, this code returns a value of 20 to me while it should actually return 24.

I implemented the exact same logic in Java and it returns me a value of 24. Is there a difference in the way the while loop is implemented in Python which is causing my loop to exit after the first iteration.

Comment: It would help if we could see the Java code that you used (although I have a hunch).

Comment: Are you sure about the 20 ? i get a 24

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - if it is Python 2 then dividing may gives wrong results - it rounts to int.

Comment: I tested in Python 2.7 and 3.4 and got 24 from both.

Comment: Oh, there are mixed tabs and spaces in your source. Use Python 3 (strongly recommended) or run with `python2 -tt`.

Comment: Keep it simple:  "100".count("0")

Comment: @gregory: It’s to count the zeroes in the factorial of 100, not just 100.

Comment: @Ryan, so why not: str(math.factorial(100)).count('0')?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the logic here?

Comment: @gregory: Because that’s too slow and uses too much memory for factorial(1000000).

Comment: @Ryan, Sure; but a simple solution for small scales seems reasonable when the OP had a trail of only 24 zeros which is most likely just factorial(76) not factorial(1000000).

Comment: @gregory: Yeah, we can also simplify it to `print 24` for scales between 100 and 100

Comment: Thank you!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021409/indentation-in-function-does-not-work-as-expected - This link had the exact solution for my problem. I had used tab to indent it instead of space which caused the problem. I'm getting the expected results now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - The logic is to count the number of 5s in the prime factors of n!

Comment: Also, in case you missed it: I really recommend upgrading from Python 2 to Python 3. It catches problems with indentation and much more.

Comment: Added a 2.x tag because this would not be reproducible as shown in 3.x - it would either work correctly, or the logically wrong indentation would be obvious, or there would be an `IndentationError`.